# Parsing XML with Python using a key

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following XML file

```
<GeocodeResponse>
   <status>OK</status>
   <result>
      <type>street_address</type>
      <formatted_address>277 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA</formatted_address>
      <address_component>
         <long_name>277</long_name>
         <short_name>277</short_name>
         <type>street_number</type>
      </address_component>
      <address_component>
      <long_name>Bedford Avenue</long_name>
      <short_name>Bedford Ave</short_name>
      <type>route</type>
   </address_component>
   <address_component>
      <long_name>Williamsburg</long_name>
      <short_name>Williamsburg</short_name>
      <type>neighborhood</type>
      <type>political</type>
   </address_component>
   <address_component>
      <long_name>11211</long_name>
      <short_name>11211</short_name>
      <type>postal_code</type>
   </address_component>
```

I am looking to return the value `11211` using `postal_code` as the key. How should I parse it and return the value as a string?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). I think this will do what you want:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_by_type(data, some_type):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'xml')
    components = soup.find('result').find_all('address_component')

    for c in components:
        if any(t for t in c.find_all('type') if t.text == some_type):
            return c.long_name.text


with open('data.xml') as f:
    data = f.read()

print(get_by_type(data, 'postal_code'))
```

You can get other values simply changing the string given as the second argument to `get_by_type`.